# My Uno 1.4 giving me a hard time loosing alot of cash on this car

Tags: starting

Uno 1.4 not starting, I had took it for wiring for the indicates and hooters drove back it switched off at a step hill and from there it's not starting what could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Really, there's no way to know. My suggestion would be to get it back to where you got the work done and have them fix their issues.

Comment: You don't say the age, but if it is an old "shopping trolley" then it may well be coincidence and nothing to do with the other work.